# Amazon sp-api. Authentication with old MWS tokens with swagger generated code

Tags: python, swagger-codegen, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying connect to Amazon using new sp-api and Hybrid approach. I took [here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/tree/main/references/authorization-api) the model and "compile" it with swagger. Then I try to execute the example code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.AuthorizationApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))
selling_partner_id = 'selling_partner_id_example' # str | The seller ID of the seller for whom you are requesting Selling Partner API authorization. This must be the seller ID of the seller who authorized your application on the Marketplace Appstore.
developer_id = 'developer_id_example' # str | Your developer ID. This must be one of the developer ID values that you provided when you registered your application in Developer Central.
mws_auth_token = 'mws_auth_token_example' # str | The MWS Auth Token that was generated when the seller authorized your application on the Marketplace Appstore.

try:
    # Returns the Login with Amazon (LWA) authorization code for an existing Amazon MWS authorization.
    api_response = api_instance.get_authorization_code(selling_partner_id, developer_id, mws_auth_token)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling AuthorizationApi->get_authorization_code: %s\n" % e)
```

but I receive the error message:

```
Exception when calling AuthorizationApi->get_authorization_code: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Thu, 03 Jun 2021 15:45:52 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '135', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '6b00b699-2ce1-4973-a155-d7ecee9d7f7b', 'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'MissingAuthenticationTokenException', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'AWvfqFUmoAMF6Yg='})
HTTP response body: {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
     "code": "MissingAuthenticationToken"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some people says [NEED HEADER](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/324) but in documentation is nothing about it.

So my question is:
How to authorize, using MWS old token??

Comment: did you solve this problem, I saw you want to use the old mws auth token to authorize sp api. But I didn't see answer below mention anything about it

Comment: no I am in the way.
If You have a design  - You are welcome. 
when I resolve the problem, I'll publish new answer ))

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx  -  btw now I'am trying create pure request for doing my task.
I have run out  swagger code and python sp-api modules

Comment: I've confirmed with amazon, they said you  have to publish you app to use authorization API endpoint, Have you published your app?

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx process in progress.
May be You are right.
I'll inform You about result )

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx   answer is here:   
https://marco-tibaldeschi.medium.com/amazon-sp-api-auth-auth-demystified-ab3bc746729b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [heare](https://marco-tibaldeschi.medium.com/amazon-sp-api-auth-auth-demystified-ab3bc746729b)

Detail explanation of handmade request authoritarian )

When my code will works I'll place it here.

Comment: did you ever get this to work? If you can post your code that'd be great!

Comment: @ToddT Yes we did
But Amazon roll down its activity. Time of transferring to new API now is so far...

Answer (score 1):

I am sure what will be IAM ARN issue or authorize URL issue.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-4-create-an-iam-role

You can get idea about state

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-3-the-selling-partner-signs-into-your-website